# Reset Photoshop CS6 layer style non-default defaults

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

Anyone have an idea how can the defaults of the "Reset to Default" button be reset, after being set with the "Make Default" button without reverting all the other photoshop settings. I would be very happy with a single-effect reset solution only, but one for all styles would do as well.

P.S. I am looking for a way not to delete the "Adobe Photoshop CS6 Prefs.psp" file. If there is no such, a guide for editing it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little trick to retain some custom layer style settings....

First, go through the layer Styles dialog and set the items you want to keep as the default if you haven't already, by clicking the **Make Default** button at the bottom of the style options screen. You need to do this for each item on the left you want to retain.

[image: make default]

Now, click the Styles link at the top left of the window and then click the default "No Style" option. This resets all the style options to their *factory* defaults rather than the *user defined defaults*.

[image: styles]

Now, with the style dialog still open, return to the style elements you want back, and click the **Reset to Default** button. This will return the style setting to what you defined previously when you clicked the Make Default button.

[image: reset]

Comment: that's a very nice solution, i think i've treated the styles menu as some unuseful thing for too long now. Thanks that's a perfect solution!!!